# Social networks buttons callback

Tags: social-networking

Is there any way to make sure that a user has truly shared a link on a social network?

I am using AddThis buttons, where am using `'addthis.menu.share'` event which only raised if a user clicked on the button without the need to really login and post to the social network, my questiton is not only about AddThis plugin, but in general is it possible to have a callback or to initiate a request to check whether the user really shared the contents?

My website scenario is that i want to inform my server side code that the user truly posted or shared a link on his/her profile, am not sure if i can accomplish this, please provide your suggestions.